# TFS Build error - Cannot listen on pipe name 'xxx' because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, build-agent

In TFS, i'm doing build for my .Net project. I've got agent configured locally and build is carried using that. Error says as follows

**Cannot listen on pipe name 'net.pipe://localhost/taskagent/6/xxxxxx' because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name.**

Not sure, what this exactly is....Please help. Attached the error screenshot for reference.
[image]
Note: I'm not using any TDD/test process in code

Comment: Did you have multiple build agents  on the build server? The screenshot above is not error screenshot, you could update  the error screenshot with verbose debug mode enable.

Comment: Yes, multiple build agents exits on TFS server. They are configured seperatly by/for individuals.

Yes, provided screenshot is not of error but of build pipeline for info

Comment: Hi Shalem, afraid the issue is  related your build agent configure or setting, could you use some other build agent to narrow down the issue. Or could you build  other definitions on the same build agent?

Comment: Hi Shalem, any update on this issue, have you figured out it?

Comment: No progress yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error info not sure if it's related to TFS side. Suggest you also manually run the build directly on the build agent.

Since the agent is newly configured, to narrow down if the error is related to your environment on the build server machine. You could also create a new build definition with a simple project such as hello world and check if got the same error. If so, suggest you delete the agent, reconfigure it follow this tutorial: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v1-windows)

Besides, you could also set `system.debug=true` to enable verbose debug for build to get more detail error info, please refer: [Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/)

Comment: I've removed the current agent and configured agent again. This helped me